# how to properly count number of matching alleles

Tags: r

I am comparing two different genotypic profiles and counting the number of matching alleles.

Comparing the profiles by eye, I count 5 matches and I know from my professor that 5 is the answer.

Now my question is how to get my code to show 5 matches.

Currently, my code is counting 7 matches but that is because it is counting two matches twice.

I was wondering how I could get my code to not count a match twice.

Thank you.

These are the profiles I am comparing:

```
genos[1,,]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12][,13]

[1,]    4    5    5   16   25   14    2    1    7    37     7     4    16

[2,]    4    5    1   14   21   10    5    5    7    16    14     3    14
```

```
genos[2,,]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]

[1,]    6    3    8    7   35   10    2    5    7    34    10    13    10

[2,]    6    3    3   10   30    7    2   23    5    22    10    13    14
```

This is the code I am currently running that gives me 7 matches.

```
nMatchingAllele = 0

for(i in 1:2) {
  for(j in 1:2) {
    for(k in 1:13){
    if(genos[1,i,k] == genos[2,j,k])
      nMatchingAllele = nMatchingAllele + 1
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for loop` in your case may not be the most efficient solution. I suggest a much simpler solution:

First, turn your alleles values into a `vector` for each profile. Since I do not have your original data,

```
genos1 <- c(4, 5, 5, 16, 25, 14, 2, 1, 7, 37, 7, 4, 16, 
            4,  5, 1, 14, 21, 10, 5, 5, 7, 16, 14, 3, 14) 
genos2 <- c(6, 3, 8, 7, 35, 10, 2, 5, 7,  34, 10, 13, 10, 
            6, 3, 3, 10, 30, 7, 2, 23, 5, 22, 10, 13, 14)
```

Then, get unique values from each vector and sum the total matched numbers:

```
uniq_g1 <- unique(genos1)
uniq_g2 <- unique(genos2)
sum(uniq_g1%in%uniq_g2)
```

We got 6 matches.

```
> sum(uniq_g1%in%uniq_g2) 
[1] 6
```

You can also sort the allele values for better eye checking:

```
uniq_g1 <- sort(unique(genos1))
uniq_g2 <- sort(unique(genos2))
sum(uniq_g1%in%uniq_g2)
uniq_g1[uniq_g1%in%uniq_g2]

> uniq_g1[uniq_g1%in%uniq_g2]
[1]  2  3  5  7 10 14
```

You can see that this (6) is different from your eye checking result (5). Please let me know if the result of 6 matches from my code is wrong.

**Edit**
To pick up those on the same "column":

```
genos1 <- data.frame(a1 = c(4, 5, 5, 16, 25, 14, 2, 1, 7, 37, 7, 4, 16), 
            a2 = c(4,  5, 1, 14, 21, 10, 5, 5, 7, 16, 14, 3, 14)) 
genos2 <- data.frame(b1 = c(6, 3, 8, 7, 35, 10, 2, 5, 7,  34, 10, 13, 10), 
            b2 = c(6, 3, 3, 10, 30, 7, 2, 23, 5, 22, 10, 13, 14))
df <- data.frame(genos1, genos2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(
    a1 == b1 | a1==b2 | a2==b1 | a2 == b2 
  ) 


  a1 a2 b1 b2
1 14 10 10  7
2  2  5  2  2
3  1  5  5 23
4  7  7  7  5
5 16 14 10 14
```

Comment: This is really close thank you! Your code is counting 3 as a match, although there is a 3 on genos 1 and 2, it is not on the same column, which would not be a match. Would there be a way to make sure it looks at each column and only count a match once?

Comment: Please be more specific about “not the same column”. Thanks

Comment: In column 1 of genos1, that individual has the genotype (4,4) and in column 1 of genos2, the individual has the genotype (6,6). If we were to compare this column with these individuals, they would not match. However, if we look at column 6, the individual genos1 has the genotype (14,10) and the individual genos2 has the genotype (10,7). Although the number 10 is not on the same row, these two individuals are still considered a match in column 6. Thus, if we compare the individuals by eye, we find 5 matches (columns 6,7,8,9, and 13).